# ImportError: No module named xmltodict while calling from other Python script

Tags: python

I am having a weird problem.

I am on Py2.7 and I am calling a py file from python script. Below is my code

**caller.py**

```
import os
import subprocess    
filename = 'file.py'

data = 'aXD'
output = subprocess.check_output(['python', filename,data], shell=False)
```

**file.py**

```
import sys
import os
import xmltodict

args = sys.argv
xml = args[1].strip('\n')
xml = xml.strip()
pid = str(os.getpid())
result = {'msg':'ok',"pid":pid}
print(result)
```

And it gives error:

```
    import xmltodict
ImportError: No module named xmltodict
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

The module is RIGHT there since the file runs perfect when executing individually.

Comment: It suggests that you have a path / include issue.  Do you have more than one python interpreter installed?  Try printing `sys.executable` in each and see what it returns?

Comment: Right where? It sounds like `caller.py` has a different working directory than when you run `file.py`.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I have Python 2.7 and 2.6 but both execute same Python. Just checked

Comment: @g.d.d.c actually you are right, it returns two path:

1)/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

2)/usr/bin/python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer, instead of in comments -> the issue is that you've got more than one python interpreter installed and you're getting a different one than you expected when you launched it via `subprocess.check_output`.  You should address that by changing your invocation like so:

```
output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, filename,data], shell=False)
```

Which will ensure, at the very least, that both scripts are run by the same interpreter.

Answer (score 10):

The issue can be resolved trough this simple way:
use 'pip' - python package manager
   `$ sudo pip install xmltodict`

This should install missing module and you shouldn't have problems with this module.

Comment: Perhaps do not install this as root, but install it into your virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

Add "current directory" to your Python path so it will find modules in the directory alongside the main program

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

Comment: This only addresses the issue if it's related to him having modules in the current script's path that are not being found by the interpreter.  That's not the case, and this won't fix his issue.  He needs to account for the presence of multiple interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

Install this package for xmltodict with conda, you need to run one of the following:

conda install -c conda-forge xmltodict
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 xmltodict
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 xmltodict

once the package xmltodict is installed, re-run the script. It will work.