# ImportError: No module named 'xmltodict'

Tags: python, pipenv, xmltodict

Relatively new to Python I've created a project using Pipenv that uses the xmltodict module.  I've looked at some similar questions but can't find exactly what I need to do.

I've used pipenv to install the xmltodict module but I'm still getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./storagereport.py", line 12, in <module>
    import xmltodict
ImportError: No module named 'xmltodict'
```

Pipenv shows that the module is installed:

```
$ pipenv graph
xmltodict==0.12.0
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like you can get and install it from [here](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) (see the instructions there on getting it).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919161

Comment: have you activated the environment?

Comment: Do you mean by running 'pipenv shell'?  Yes I did that and am executing commands within it

Answer (score 4):

Try with following command:

```
sudo pip install xmltodict
```

or

```
sudo pip install xmltodict --upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be running Python from another version , which is usually the default version that is installed. If that's the case, in your virtual environment you will find `python.exe` and `pip.exe` you have to run pip from the virtual environment

Comment: I'm running the pip/pip3 and python3 ./storageport.py within the pipenv shell, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I run into this regularly, I believe because I'm behind a firewall. I download the package that I need to my computer and then I install it. If that doesn't work, I navigate to the download folder where it is and install it from there. You can download this package here:

https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/

Comment: In the question it is confirmed that the module is installed: "Pipenv shows that the module is installed" why dou you assume that it is not?

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to reply with the full command output, I'll edit the original

Answer (score 0):

I **downloaded** the file from here- https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/#files and after **extraction** placed the **.py file** in the **directory** where I was importing xmltodict. Then it worked fine.